# Calling javascript via PHP not working

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, function

I got a function that checks the value of a form and displays it to you before submission. Its written outside of PHP, but PHP is writing the HTML to call it when the user hits submit.

Well, I want to make it do more. I want it to display 2 values. I got it to do that, but I need it to pass the second value through PHP before displaying it. Basically the 2nd value is a number, and the number acts as an index key for an array with messages in it.

I figure it's as easy as passing more parameters to the function, but,

I need to know how to write that. I know you need to use double, not single quotes in order to parse variables in PHP, but the problem is the onClick already required double quotes, and breaking it into multiple echo statements doesn't seem to be working.

I swear, I change even one little thing about the javascript and for some reason it wont work at all.

I have no idea what's going on.

Here's a rough of the code.

```
Echo "<input type='submit' value='derrrrr' onClick='return confirmSubmit(this.form)' /></form>";
```

Where `this.form` is, I also need to pass `$thearray[]` (into the function).

Comment: "I have no idea what's going on." Neither do we. Plz post code.

Comment: Can you post your code from the section in question?

Comment: Fine but I'm on my phone gimme a sec

Comment: "I'm on my phone so I gotta keep this short."  This isn't a forum.  If you can't be bothered to take the time to write a full question, we can't really help you.  If you can't post the full question right away, wait until you can.  We're not gonna wait for you.  Remember this is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: Hi @user1159454. In your web browser, are you using a JS console or error log? This is available in all browsers - I use Firefox but Chrome or Safari are good to dev with also. When executing JS, you'll see any errors as they happen - making tracking down bugs much easier.

Comment: Halfer that's pretty awesome I didn't know about that, I mostly use firefox. And sorry, I've written the part of the code that I think is troublesome though.

Answer (score 0):

Escape quotes in PHP by adding a slash before them.

For example:

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"jsFunction();\">Click me</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Why not simplier, using `echo '<a href="#" onclick="jsFunction();">Click me</a>';`?